# How can I create one page for two dynamic routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, routes

I use the newest version of nextjs with app router, and I'm a little bit stuck with route organization.

I need routing like that, but can`t figure out how to do it

```
catalog/[category]/[id] ===> id.jsx
catalog/[category] ===> catalog.jsx
catalog ===> catalog.jsx
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your folder structure like this:

```
catalog
  - page.tsx (=> <Catalog/>)
  - [category]
    - page.tsx (=> <Catalog/>)
    - [id]
      - page.tsx
```

Answer (score 1):

```
src/ (Folder)
└── catalog/(Folder)
    └── [category]/(Folder) 
        └── [id] / (Folder)
              |_pages.jsx (File)
```

This can be accomplished using a combination of file-based routing as you mentioned. You want catalog/[category]/[id] and catalog/[category] to route to different pages, but catalog should route to the same page as catalog/[category].

You can place a page.jsx file inside of the category folder and style that but when someone reaches your pages.jsx file via routing they will see the category page.jsx as well.